# When You Ask a Question to Answer a Question

Tags: discussion

...and the answer you get for the second question answers the first question but doesn't answer the question it was under.

I've been working on answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741560/) and in doing so, I wrote some basic code that ended up having some unwanted behavior.

I pulled my hair out for about 2 hours, then I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742269/).

Although the user wasn't able to determine why it didn't work, @Santiago Rebella was able to provide me with revised code that did work.

Now, the code that @Santiago Rebella also would work for the original question and I posted it in my answer to allow the OP to go about his business.

However, I have certain doubts if that is the way to go. Was that the proper way to go in the Stack Overflow Community?

Comment: Well, you attribute it to the person who answered your question. I doubt that the original question could/should be closed as a duplicate, but if you don't want to get reputation for it, maybe you could make it a community wiki answer :) Also, mention to the answerer of your question that you posted his code on the original question, maybe he can chime in ;) Oh, and you mark the answer you got as an answer :p

Comment: @Icepickle Okay, thanks. However, regarding the question, I still haven't discovered why in the world it's not working!